# get frame child view in js ... Get the size of the artbox in the pdf file

Tags: javascript

Importing a pdf file from the default folder is the viewbox size. How to get the internal size of the pdf file which is the artbox. For example, I import a pdf with dimensions of 236mm*323mm. In that pdf file there is an A4 sheet of paper so how do I get that size?

I'm trying to declare the pdf.js library but it doesn't show up

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.